# Simple pregunta de !NOT porque no me devuelve lo que yo pienso

Tags: javascript, if

Centrandonos en esta parte => **Number(!numeroUsuario)** Porque no me devuelve **'Por favor, introduce algún valor.** y si funciona con **!Number(numeroUsuario)** No entiendo bien del todo, cuando pongo 0 en el prompt es un cero string, que es por default true, y como lo que quiero es que si pongo un 0 me lo rechace y me diga  'Por favor, introduce algún valor le pongo ! delante, vale, pero no entiendo porque se le pone delante del Number???

```js
let numeroUsuario, modulo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');

  if (numeroUsuario === null) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.');
  } else if(Number(!numeroUsuario) || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '') {
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.');
  } else {
    if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
      modulo = 'par';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    } else {
      modulo = 'impar';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por que estas negando `0` como un boleano. Estas negando `!0` que es igual a `true` que se puede convertir en `1`. En javascript `1==true`. Después obtienes que `Number(1) == true` y entra como si fuera un valor correcto pero el valor de `numeroUsuario` sigue siendo `0`.

Necesitas negar el resultado de `Number(0)== false` para que se convierta en `true` y te muestre el mensaje de error. Como lo estas haciendo estas evaluando mal.

Esta parte de aqui `Number(0)== false` te esta diciendo que no es un número. Pero tu estas convirtiendo el `0` en `1` con `!` así que de ahí viene el error. Primero debes evaluar que el dato es un número, luego negarlo para que entre a la segunda parte de tu `ifelse`.

En tu código puse algunas alertas para que veas como va evaluandose el script y entiendas el error que es de aplicación de conceptos. Recuerda que en jscript no es necesario definir tipos así que un `1` y `0` pueden representar `true` y `false`, por tanto puede ser modificado por `!`.

También te pongo una alerta para que veas como se evalua un número al usar este mismo operador (cuando el número es diferente de 1)

**Es importante entender esta forma de trabajar en javascript. Puedes hacer conversiones entre tipos de datos sin darte cuenta y es lo que estás haciendo. Es algo intrincado.**

---

**Esto pasa divido en pasos (  xO )**

1. `Number(!0)` se convierte en `Number(true)` por que `0=false`
2. `Number(true)` se convierte en `Number(1)` por que `1=true`
3. `Number(1)` se convierte en `True`
4. No truenan tus chicharrones.

**Esto es lo que quieres que pase:**

1. `!Number(0)` se evalua y se convierte en `!false`
2. `!false` se convierte en `true`;
3. Truenan tus chicharrones.

```js
  alert( "Esto es lo que quieres !Number(0) = " + !Number("0"));
alert( "Esto es lo que estas haciendo mal Number(!0) = " + Number(!0));
alert("Esto pasa con un string '0' = " + Boolean("0"));
alert( "Por que !0= " + !0);
alert(Number(!"0") +"--"+ Number(!0));

alert("Evaluando numeros: 2 " + Boolean(2));
alert("Evaluando numeros: 9 " + Boolean(9));
alert("Evaluando numeros: !9 " + (!9) + "Aquí paso una conversión de tipo sin que te dieras cuenta. ");


let numeroUsuario, modulo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');

  if (numeroUsuario === null) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.');
  } else if(!Number(numeroUsuario) || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '') {
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.');
  } else {
    if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
      modulo = 'par';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    } else {
      modulo = 'impar';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo porque dices que estoy haciendo mal esto => Number(!0) cuando al introducir un 0 en el prompt es '0' osea Number(!'0') lo que convierte el '0' string en 0

Comment: Recuerda que javascript hace la conversión entre tipos de manera automática. El string que introduces en el prompt se transforma en boleano cuando aplicas el operador `!`. Te lo puse en la sección de "esto pasa divido en pasos" de la respuesta.

Comment: Ah es verdad Angel, pero si lo hace de forma automatica porque es necesario usar Number? Perdona por tanta pregunta

Comment: Vale si claro perdona estoy bobo, la conversion a numero siempre la tengo que hacer(en este caso porque quiero un 0) y con el ! lo invierto

Comment: Jajaja vale lo veo mil veces mas claro quiero invertir el 0 numerico que he convertido con Number que es false a true y ahi entra en mi primer bloque, me siento un estupido ahora jajaja

Comment: @fran Suele pasar.

Comment: Angel, otra cosa si tienes tiempo, entendi lo que me dijiste pero podrias ver mi pregunta en este link? Es seguro una tonteria. Mil gracias si me ayudas
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124774/porque-un-2-numero-o-string-2-da-false

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` returna un `string`, no un `Number`. Por lo que al momento de hacer `!"0"` da falso.

Intenta conviertiendo el valor a `Number` utilizando `parseInt()`:

```js
let numeroUsuario, modulo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');

  if (numeroUsuario === null) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.');
  } else if(Number(!parseInt(numeroUsuario)) || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '') {
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.');
  } else {
    if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
      modulo = 'par';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    } else {
      modulo = 'impar';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    }
  }
}
```