# ¿Por qué un 2 número o string '2' da false?

Tags: javascript

Buenas, soy nuevo en esto,  simple pregunta de conceptos. Se que un 0 string en un prompt da true porque no es un 0 numerico, ¿por qué aquí me da false? ¿Al igual que un string de 2?
¿Algo hago mal para comprobar si es true? 
O ¿debería comprobarlo como pone mas abajo?
Muchas gracias

```js
var a = 0;
    var b = 1;
    var c = 2;
    var d = '0';
    var e = '1';
    var f = '2';

    console.log(a == true); //false
    console.log(b == true); //true
    console.log(c == true); //false
    console.log(d == true); //false
    console.log(e == true); //true
    console.log(f == true); //false
    
//O deberia verlo asi=>
    
console.log(!!a); // false
console.log(!!b); // true
console.log(!!c); // true
console.log(!!d); // true
console.log(!!e); // true
console.log(!!f); // true
```

Comment: Acostúmbrate a comparar con === y !==.

Answer (score 10):

Cuando se utiliza el operador `==` entre dos tipos diferentes, lo que se hace es convertir uno de ellos al otro y despues compararles. Cuando la comparación es entre número y booleano, se convierte siempre el booleano a numérico. Esto es, false=0,true=1. Ahora verás claro los 3 primeros ejemplos:

```
0 == true => 0 == 1 => false
1 == true => 1 == 1 => true
2 == true => 2 == 1 => false
```

En cuanto a los segundos ejemplos, tanto el carácter como el booleano se convierten a numero, y se comparan:

```
'0' == true => 0 == 1 => false
'1' == true => 1 == 1 => true
'2' == true => 2 == 1 => false
```

Answer (score 5):

Fíjate que `0` significa falso y `1` significa verdadero.

En el primero estas preguntando si **a** es verdadero, en este caso no porque vale 0 que significa falso, por eso devuelve falso.

Después **b** como vale 1 pues si devuelve true. Pero claro después tienes que **c=2** pero el no puede evaluar esa variable, porque un boolean solo puede ser False(0) o True(1), por eso devuelve false.

En los otros casos pasa lo mismo, cuando encuentra un carácter lo intenta convertir a entero, entonces como **d** y **e** son booleanos puede hacer la conversión y evaluarlos.

Espero haberte ayudado y haberme explicado bien.

Saludos!!!

Answer (score 2):

no se bien a que te refieres , pero si comparas con `==` obtendrás un resultado , pero si comparas con `===` obtendrás otro, todos te darán **false** dado que este ultimo compara hasta el punto de verificar si son el mismo tipo de datos, al usar `==` y no comparar el mismo tipo de datos, vera **0** como **false** y **1** como **true**, cuando utilizas `===` en la comparación `1===true` responderá **false** porque 1 es un dato numérico y true un dato booleano

Answer (score 2):

Estás comparando diferentes tipos de datos, por lo cuál se transforman a números y estos son diferentes,

p.e:

```js
var c = parseInt('2') == true ; console.log(c);

// 2 es diferente de 1, por eso falso
```

Además NUNCA uses el operador débil , usa el buen operador en su lugar:

```
===
```

Ya que el operador débil puede dar resultados inesperados.

**Más información aquí:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Si quieres hacer un condicional con alguno de esos datos, deberías hacer:

```js
var c = '2';

if(c) console.log(`Es ${c}`);

// ó

if(Boolean(c) === true) console.log(`Es ${c} ! `);
```